# Rotating a modal UIViewController with custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom UIViewController category which applies a transition blurring the parent and pushing it back and up a bit.

It looks like this:

[image]

I'm creating a blurred screenshot of the parent in `animateTransition`, associate it with `obj_setAssociatedObject` to the presented viewcontroller and remove it after dismiss.

It works like a charm, however when I rotate to landscape the background view won't rotate, which is expected :

[image: image2]

I tried to add notifications in `animateTransition` for orientation changes, but since it's the inside of the transition manager it will get dealloced after the transition finishes (I assume).

Tried to associate the transition manager object to the presented VC, but no luck.

How could I update the blurred view from inside the transition manager or in combination with the parent category when the orientation changes ? ( iOS 7 compatible )

Category :

```
- (void)presentCustom:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent
                                     completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    viewControllerToPresent.transitioningDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:YES completion:completion];
}

- (void)dismissCustom:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:completion];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did came up with the following, it seems to work, might be helpful for someone in this situation.

```
//#import "NSObject+AssociatedObjects.h" 

// in animateTransition , presenting part 
// adds self to the presented controller
[toViewController associateValue:self withKey:&kTransitionManagerAssocKey];
// adds sourceVS to self 
[self associateValue:fromViewController withKey:&kOriginalViewControllerAssocKey];
// adds the blurred image to presentedVC
[toViewController associateValue:blurImageView withKey:&kBlurImageAssocKey];
// adds presentedVC to self
[self associateValue:toViewController withKey:&kPresentedViewControllerAssocKey];
// Register for orientation changes, so we can update the presenting controller screenshot
// in the method get the original controller, render it in the existing blurred view or replace it and readd it to the container
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(transitionManager_interfaceOrientationDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and for the dismissing part everything needs to be cleaned up :

```
// get the associated manager and clear everything
TransitionManager * oldManager = [fromViewController associatedValueForKey:&kTransitionManagerAssocKey];
if (oldManager)
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:oldManager name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
   [oldManager associateValue:nil withKey:&kOriginalViewControllerAssocKey];
   [oldManager associateValue:nil withKey:&kPresentedViewControllerAssocKey];
   [fromViewController associateValue:nil withKey:&kTransitionManagerAssocKey];
}
// this one is cleared when the transition is complete
[fromViewController associateValue:nil withKey:&kBlurImageAssocKey];
```